# Optimize SQL query for given Conditions

Tags: sql, database, oracle, optimization

I have a query of the form:

```
select SUM(some_column) from (table) 

where 

IF x then a

ELSE y then b

ELSE z then c

...
```

Now in my JAVA code,i call this query for every different value(x,y,z,...),which returns me required sum.My objective is to calculate the **Total sum** for all those values,i.e,

```
Total = SUM_for_x + SUM_for_y + SUM_for_z + ....
```

Now,off course,I am hitting the DB for every such value,which is costly.Can i optimize this in 1 single query which does the job for me,hitting the DB just once ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are only interested in the total sum and not in the partial sums and the conditions are mutually exclusive, you can do this:

```
SELECT SUM(some_column)
  FROM (table)
 WHERE (a)
    OR (b)
    OR (c)
    OR ...
```

An other way (if your conditions are not mutually exclusive) would be:

```
SELECT SUM(some_column)
  FROM(SELECT SUM(some_column) AS some_column FROM (table) WHERE (a) UNION ALL
       SELECT SUM(some_column) AS some_column FROM (table) WHERE (b) UNION ALL
       SELECT SUM(some_column) AS some_column FROM (table) WHERE (c) -- UNION ALL a.s.o.
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(case when x then a end) sum_a, 
       SUM(case when y then b end) sum_b, 
       SUM(case when z then c end) sum_c
  FROM <table>
```

and sum up in Java

or get total in SQL:

```
SELECT SUM(case when x then a end) sum_a + 
       SUM(case when y then b end) sum_b + 
       SUM(case when z then c end) sum_c 
  FROM <table>
```